# How to determine if any values in an object are non-null?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In Javascript, I am processing some JSON data that takes the form:

```
o = {
  a: null,
  b: null,
  c: 1,
  d: null
  // ... 10 or so other properties that are either null or numerical
}
```

I'm trying to write a quick function that will process the whole object to determine if there are any non-null values for any of the keys.  Any suggestions to do this efficiently and with just a few lines of code?  My project already uses underscore.js, so if that can speed things up or make it briefer, all the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about the one-liner,

```
_.any(_.values(a), function (v) { return !_.isNull(v) });
```

which will return true if there is at least one non-null value.

Comment: It looks like `_.any(a, function (v) { return !_.isNull(v) });` works just as well.  I confirmed that if you pass an object to _.any, it simply iterates through the keys and gets the values for each keys and tests those with the iterator function. Any reason not to use this even shorter version?

Comment: Indeed it will work since the iterator will be passed (value, key) as arguments. Having only one, will simply discard the key. You should be fine...

Comment: i like to use `values` to help other devs know what kind of object you're working with...  `_.every(_.values(a), _.isNull)`

Answer (score 3):

```
var hasVal = false;
for (var prop in obj) {
    hasVal = obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] !== null;
    if (hasVal) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`_.find`](http://underscorejs.org/#find) in combination with [`_.isNull`](http://underscorejs.org/#isNull):

```
var has_a_null = _.chain(o).find(_.isNull).isNull().value();
```

or similarly:

```
var has_a_null = _(o).find(_.isNull) === null
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/t678w/